# Cronjob macOS does not work if set with a bash external script

Tags: macos, catalina, bash, cron

I'm trying to create a new cronjob which launches a script every time at startup. If I do `cronjob -e` and then I insert for example `@reboot bash /Users/user/script.sh` and then I save everything is fine:

```
crontab: no crontab for user - using an empty one
crontab: installing new crontab
```

If I reboot my mac the script gets executed successfully. What I'm attempting to do is to create a cronjob with a bash script just like this:

```
var=$(crontab -l 2> /dev/null);
value=$(echo $?);
script='@reboot bash /Users/user/myscript.sh';

if [[ $value = 0 ]];
then
    printf "$var \n$script" |crontab -;
else
    printf "$script" | crontab -;
fi
```

It seems to work because if I do `crontab -l` I find my script `@reboot bash /Users/user/myscript.sh` but after restarting the Mac, the script does not get executed. Any ideas why it is not working, and how can I get it to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check whether there currently is a crontab installed or not. Just run

```
(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo '@reboot bash /Users/user/myscript.sh') | crontab -
```

to add the `@reboot` line to your crontab (or create a new one).

Comment: thank you, this is easier. I tried before a much similar method but it did overwrite the other crontab

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Crontab needs `\n` at the end of the latest line to execute commands:

```
var=$(crontab -l 2> /dev/null);
value=$(echo $?);
script='@reboot bash /Users/angelorosa/script.sh';

if [[ $value = 0 ]];
then
    printf "$var\n$script\n" | crontab;
else
    printf "$script \n" | crontab;
fi
```

Comment: Embedding arbitrary strings (like the old crontab contents) in a `printf` control string is not safe. Use something like `printf '%s\n' "$var" "$script"` instead.